# Open Cmis API has no access to Alfresco's "Inherit Parent Space Permissions"

Tags: liferay, acl, alfresco, cmis

I'm working on a liferay portlet similar to 'Documents and Media', that connects to an Alfresco repository, and using the apache chemistry open cmis API to interact with repository items.

I'm almost done with applying Permissions through ACEs, but I have a major issue, dealing with alfresco's "Inherit Parent Space Permissions" feature which propagates the parent folder's properties to all the children. Looks like this feature is not supported by cmis, but I have to find a way to edit this property from liferay.

Although there isn't any available high-level API to edit this property, I guess I can make a workaround by using the Alfresco's REST API.
Doing something like [this](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=45182) maybe.

But before doing that I'd like to make sure there is no other way to do that. I mean, it's a pretty major feature missing here. If I understand correctly, if you can't have access to that property you can choose between :

1. Disabling the inheritance for all items, and lose the benefits
   from the inheritance and ACL propagation.
2. Or Enabling the
   inheritance for all Spaces, and since ACL works like granting-rules
   (and not restricting ones), having the children resources always less
   restricted as you navigate deeper in the repository. This way, you
   end up having all the restricted resource pretty close to the
   'company home' space, and put the higher-availability resources very
   deep in the repository space structure.
3. Or Having the inheritance enabled, and each time you want to remove a single permission from a
   child resource, make a call to alfresco from another lower level API,
   disable the inheritance (and lose all the propagated ACEs, desired or
   not), then add again the necessary aces.

This doesn't sound reasonable to me, so I'm really afraid I'm missing something here, like a major high-level API feature. Could someone please tell me if I'm on the right track, and whether or not is the lower-level API calls the only option available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMIS does not support changing the ACL inheritance setting. You can determine which ACE's are inherited, but you can't turn inheritance on and off. You'll have to write your own web script and call that from your portlet.

Comment: I didn't know I can determine which ACE's are inherited. Actually I might prefer doing that. Thank you !